# Calling anonymous method recursively in angular controller method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send ajax requests at regular intervals from the angular controller method. for that i have written code like below.

```
var mainApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);
mainApp.controller('controller', function($scope,$http,$window,$timeout) {
     $('#radioBtn a').on('click', function(){
            $http({
                method:,
                url:,
                params:{parameters}
            }).then(function(success){
            },function(error){
            });

           $timeout(function(){
               //how to call the anonymous function passed to $('#radioBtn                 a').on() here.
           },30000);

        });
```

I am not getting how to call the anonymous method from timeout function. Using this() is failing.

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
var mainApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);
mainApp.controller('controller', function($scope,$http,$window,$interval) {
     $('#radioBtn a').on('click', function(){


           $interval(function(){
               $http({
                  method:,
                  url:,
                  params:{parameters}
               }).then(function(success){
               },function(error){
               });      
           },30000);

        });
```

Comment: He would have to inject $interval here instead of $timeout. This is however pretty dangerous. As a new interval will be triggered everytime you push the button.

Answer (score 0):

First off: Don't bind to element clicks like that, use the `ng-click` directive - in fact, just don't even load jQuery in your application, in 99% cases you're better off without it.

Second: Use angular's `$interval` service. Check the code sample below.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  
  $scope.numbers = [];
  $scope.startInterval = function() {       
    $scope.interval = $interval(function() {
      $scope.numbers.push($scope.numbers.length);
    }, 1000)      
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button ng-if="!interval" ng-click="startInterval()">Start polling</button>
    <div ng-repeat="number in numbers">
      {{number}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```